# Representation of the formula P(n) = (n!)(6^n) in C

Tags: c, mathematics

I'm trying to represent the following mathematical expression in C:

$$P(n)=(n!)(6^n)$$

The first program should compute the answer to expression when n = 20. I have attempted to create the program in C and it produces the correct answer (when compared with wolfram alpha's answer). The answer is approximately \$10^{34}\$.

Is there any way that I could improve the code?:

```
#include <math.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

void main()
{
    uint n=20;
    double F=1,pwr,P;

    pwr=pow(6,n);

    while(n>0){
        F=F*n;
        n=n-1;
    }
    P=F*pwr;
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `while( n > 1 ) F *= n--;`

Comment: What do you plan to do with the result, other than discarding it?

Comment: I'm writing a report. I've been instructed that there is no need to print the result. However, do you think I should change 'void main' to 'int main' and add a 'return P' at the end?

Comment: Definitely not return P, main returns an `int`, what is `P`?

Comment: P is the number of permutations.

Comment: Return value of `main` should typically be `0`, that means "finished without errors". It's not about the solution, it's about the environment it's run in.

Answer (score 6):

Because the result is on the order of \$10^{34}\$, as you have correctly noted, even a `double` will not be able to accurately represent all digits of such a large result.  We know this because it would take 
$$\frac{34}{\log_{10}2} \approx 113 \text{ bits}$$
to represent such a result, and a double isn't that large on any architecture you're likely to be using.

This then requires that we resort to multiple precision math.  Just as with multiple-digit multiplication you learned when you were very young, multiple-precision multiplication is the same principle: multiply digit by digit, adding the carry from the previous result.  In this sample code, rather than having a "digit" be 10, I've chosen 1000 which results in fewer math operations.

```
// calculate P(n) = (n!)(6^n)
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

const uint OVERFLOWVALUE = 1000;

void multiply(uint *a, unsigned adigits, uint b)
{
    uint carry = 0;
    for ( ; adigits; --adigits, ++a) {
        *a = *a * b + carry;
        if (*a >= OVERFLOWVALUE) {
            carry = *a / OVERFLOWVALUE;
            *a = *a % OVERFLOWVALUE;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
}

void print(uint *P, unsigned digits) 
{
    // print results
    for (unsigned i = digits; i; --i)
        printf("%3.3u ", P[i-1]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned digits = 12;
    uint P[digits]; 
    // initialize P
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < digits; ++i)
        P[i] = 0;

    uint n=20;

    printf("{n!*n^6, n=%u} = ", n);
    for (P[0] = 1; n; --n) {
        multiply(P, digits, n*6);
    }
    print(P, digits);
}
```

The result on this machine:

```
{n!*n^6, n=20} = 008 895 075 211 041 185 783 708 532 080 640 000
```

This agrees precisely with the Wolfram Alpha result.

### More mathematical explanation

The `multiply` routine multiplies a multiple-precision result pointed to by `a` with `adigits` values by single value `b`.  It does not check for mathematical overflow in its calculations, so we need to be careful about the range.

For calculation purpose, suppose that a `uint` type has 32 bits.  If we assume that `a` is well-formed before the calculation, how big can `b` be without risking numerical overflow?  In this case, the largest number that can be in any "digit" is 1000, so overflow will happen whenever \$b * 1000 > 2^{32}\$.  This implies that to avoid overflow, $$b < \frac{2^{32}}{1000}$$ $$b <= 4294967$$.  With this maximum possible value, the `carry` value would be 4294, which is greater than 1000, so to be pedantic, the code should actually check each digit *before* each multiplication to normalize the value.

Without this precaution, however, the calculation is still free from overflow as long as \$(999+6n)6n < 2^{32}\$.  This is a simple quadratic equation, with the largest positive root being just over 10839, so as long as \$n<10839\$ this code will work correctly as is.

Answer (score 5):

This is a two-trick question, There are a few things to note here:

- \$n!\$ is \$ 1 \times 2 \times ... \times n\$
- \$6^n\$ is \$ 6 \times 6 \times ... \times 6\$

Trick 1: This can be solved with a single loop:

```
result = 1;
while (n >= 1)  {
    result *= 6 * n;
    n--;
}
```

Trick 2: The precision of standard integer data types are not able to accommodate the size of factorial numbers up to 20 or so. You need to adjust your calculations to do manual overflows, and so on, when you calculate this way. I would consider using a long-form arbitrary precision multiplier for it.

### Code Style

note that it is no longer good practice in C to pre-declare your variables at the top of each method. You should be declaring them where they are used. Additionally, capital-case single-letter variable names are not friendly. `P` and `F` should be `product` and `factorial` or something.

Comment: "no longer good practice" When was it good practice, and why was it good practice?\

Comment: @hexafraction, anecdotally, I've seen most C variables written that way...not necessarily at the top of the function, but at least at the top of the block scope. "Here's the variables I'm going to use....now let's do it."

Comment: @PaulDraper That's because you *had* to declare all variables at the beginning of the scope in C89. This was relaxed in C99 (where you can declare variables anywhere) but C99 is still not supported everywhere, e.g. MSVC (Visual Studio) in C mode won't compile unless all variables are at the beginning of the scope.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you have provided is not working as you are using a `double` (8 bytes),without losing precision you can store a number up to \$10^{18}\$. Overflow is occurring in your result.  The solution is to use your own data structure or use a library to handle big integers in C.

Comment: You might want to add *"without losing precision"* to your "store a number up to 10^18"

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg any further suggestions to improve answer.I have written code for repeated squaring to comput 6^20 should I include that?

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to say that overflow is occurring. Have you tested this behavior in C?

Comment: Indeed I have tested this and only then written the solution.